# How to convert data in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have CSV data, for example, `A+12, A+13, A+14` (those are chr)

what kind of function I should use when I change those data to just numbers?

```
like A+12 -> 12
     A+13 -> 13
     A+14 -> 14
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use parse_number from readr package:

```
> library(readr)
> dat <- data.frame(col1 = c('A+12','A+13','A+14'), stringsAsFactors = F)
> dat
  col1
1 A+12
2 A+13
3 A+14
> dat$number <- parse_number(dat$col1)
> dat
  col1 number
1 A+12     12
2 A+13     13
3 A+14     14
```

Using base R

```
> gsub('(.*)(\\d\\d+$)','\\2', dat$col1)
[1] "12" "13" "14"
>
```

Adding your scenario:

```
> dat <- data.frame(col1 = c('A+12', 'B+51', 'A+36', 'B+55', 'B+3' ,'A+31'), stringsAsFactors = F)
> dat
  col1
1 A+12
2 B+51
3 A+36
4 B+55
5  B+3
6 A+31
> dat$number <- parse_number(dat$col1)
> dat %>% mutate(number = case_when(substr(col1, 1,1 ) == 'A' ~ number,
+                                   substr(col1, 1,1 ) == 'B' ~ number * -1))
  col1 number
1 A+12     12
2 B+51    -51
3 A+36     36
4 B+55    -55
5  B+3     -3
6 A+31     31
>
```

Comment: what should I do if I want to 12 for A+12 and -12 for B+12?

Comment: You mean all numbers followed by A are positive and all numbers following B negative? Can you share sample data here, you data just has A+

Comment: A+12
B+51
A+36
B+55
B+3
A+31

like this
so A+31 goes to 31, B+3 goes to -3

Comment: Have added code with sample data showing your scenario, please check if that works for you.

Comment: If it does answer, can you please mark my answer using the tick mark next to the code.

Answer (score 0):

`substr(x,a,b)` takes any `x` object with strings, and "cut" them on their `a`'th and `b`'th letter positions, so you can do `substr("A+12",3,4)` to get only `"12"`, and then turn it to numeric with `as.numeric()`:

```
as.numeric(substr("A+12",3,4))
```

Edit1: As the number of letter each string varies, we'll need to change the code. say your data frame is called `df`, with the column you described is `old`:

```
new = numeric() # Create an empty vector
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
    new[i] = as.numeric(substr(df$old[i], 3, nchar(df$old[i])))}
# Get from the 3rd to the last letter of string

df$new = c(new[1:100], -new[101:200])
```

OBS: if you wanted to make this code more general, you could do:

```
df$new = c(new[grep("A", df$old)], -new[grep("B", df$old)])
```

As `grep` returns the indexes of where the patter "A"/"B" was matched in df$old.

Edit2: The nice function that Karthik S showed can simplify a lot the code:

```
new = readr::parse_number(df$old)

df$new = c(new[1:100], -new[101:200])
```

Or

```
df$new = c(new[grep("A", df$old)], -new[grep("B", df$old)])
```

Comment: What if I want to make A+12 -> -12 ?

Comment: Also, more than 50 values are in the csv file. Is there a function that can be changed at once?

Comment: 2nd comment: substr takes any object, so you can do `as.numeric(substr(df,3,4))` (where `df` would be the name of your file).

1st comment: do you want do add the minus into every element? if yes, do  `-as.numeric(substr(df,3,4))`, if not, share more info on what exactly you need.
PS: don't be afraid of sharing the context of why do you need to know how to solve a problem (as long as you keep it objective), by doing so we can think of better solutions :)

Comment: The values in all columns are A+1, ... A+100, B+1, ... B+100.
I'd like to mutate this column to another column. So original column for A+1, ..., A+100, B+1...B+100 to new column 1, 2, 3 ... 100 , -1, -2, -3

Comment: it shows error..
Error: Assigned data `c(new[grep("R", df$old)], -new[grep("D", df$old)])` must be compatible with existing data. x Existing data has 50 rows. x Assigned data has 49 rows. ℹ Only vectors of size 1 are recycled.

Comment: Try using the `df$new = c(new[1:100], -new[101:200])` approach then @user14462808